# using bigint class c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, biginteger

I am solving a problem where I need to deal with 120 digit binary numbers. there is no simple data type and I have understood I need to use bigint. I am using 64 bit win 7 HB and visual studio 2010 ultimate as my ide for c++.

Can any one explain how do I create variable of bigint and how do I perform functions of square and square root on them.

Comment: By reading the documentation of the "big integer" library you are using?

Comment: An alternative is [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), which comes with an attractive C++ interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this library..
https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/

and perform calculations as normal..

```
a = 12333333333333333333333333333333333;
cout << a * a;
```

Comment: Can this example possibly work? This should mean that the language itself needs to understand a numerical literal of that size.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenSSL project provides a Big Integer library.
Google "OpenSSL Big Integer"